# symfony DoctrineBehaviors

Tags: php, symfony

I need help with translatable in symfony 3.4.

I'm useing the Bundle KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors and want to set the translations in a controller.

```
$data = [
    "token" => "jksdlfnhvbji89erje%&",
    "data" => [
        ["locale" => "en", "content" => "Value1"],
        ["locale" => "de", "content" => "Value2"],
    ]
];
foreach($data['data'] as $item){
    $firma->translate($item['locale'], true)->setKurzBeschreibung( $value );
}

$em->persist($firma);
$firma->mergeNewTranslations();
$result = $em->flush();
```

The first Time everthing works fine.
Now i want to change the Values:

```
$data = [
    "token" => "jksdlfnhvbji89erje%&",
    "data" => [
        ["locale" => "en", "content" => ""],
        ["locale" => "de", "content" => "Value2"],
    ]
];
foreach($data['data'] as $item){
    $firma->translate($item['locale'], true)->setKurzBeschreibung( $value );
}

$em->persist($firma);
$firma->mergeNewTranslations();
$result = $em->flush();
```

Works Fine. And Now

```
$data = [
    "token" => "jksdlfnhvbji89erje%&",
    "data" => [
         ["locale" => "en", "content" => "Value1"],
         ["locale" => "de", "content" => "Value2"],
    ]
];
foreach($data['data'] as $item){
    $firma->translate($item['locale'], true)->setKurzBeschreibung( $value );
}

$em->persist($firma);
$firma->mergeNewTranslations();
$result = $em->flush();
```

Dosen't store the "content" of en. The Field in the Table is still empty.

Waht can i do??